# Selected file not detected when calling VSCode command using keybinding

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have registered the following command *extension.addFile* in **explorer/context** menu and it returns the selected file uri whenever I invoke the command from the context menu.

```
commands.registerCommand('extension.addFile', async (selectedFile: Uri) =>{
  console.log(selectedFile);
}
```

However, if the command is fired with keybinding shortcut then it fails to return the selected file uri.

**Note :** This command is properly included in **keybindings**, no issue on that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to see if selectedFile uri is null then fetch the information of the actively open file. This will work because whenever you click/select a file it will open it in the current activeTextEditor and after that, if you call the command using key binding, it will return you the file uri.

```
if (!selectedFile) {
        if (window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName.length) {
            window.showInformationMessage('file found ' + window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName);
        }
        window.showInformationMessage('No file is selected');
}
```